# Make backoffice generated drop down menu choice compulsory

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a drop down menu that is generated by a backoffice. Unfortunately the backoffice does not make it required for the user to make a choice with the drop down menu. It there a way to add a script that acts on the following code to make a choice compulsory?

The code of the drop down (which I cannot change directly):

```
<select name="variant" id="product_configure_variants" onchange="document.getElementById('product_configure_form').action = 'http://www.my-domain-name.com/product/variants/22320866/'; document.getElementById('product_configure_form').submit();">
      <option value="39702636" selected="selected">PLEASE SELECT</option>
      <option value="39702638">2 APR - 16 APR 16 - €2.000,00</option>
      <option value="39702640">5 NOV - 19 JAN 16 - €3.000,00</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use change event.

Every and every change to check what is the index of the selected option.

```
var e = $("#product_configure_variants");
var error = $("#error")
var valid = false;
e.change(function() {
  if (e[0].selectedIndex === 0) {
    error.text("You must choose an option");
  } else {
    valid = true;
    error.text("");
  }
})
```

Working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/05bk4OYKZdMK3X6aZE7E?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Added all the code and attributes as described but can still leave dropdown unused without error.

Comment: You can disable the submit button as long as the vaild var is false

Comment: Or just enable him on every change

Comment: Thanks. How would I go about disabling  the submit button if I may ask?  This is my button code: <a href="javascript:;" onclick="$('#product_configure_form').submit();" title="Add to cart" class="btn large">
        Add to cart
      </a>